# How to clone a GitHub repo inside a directory mapped as a volume using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` similar to:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
    image: ....

    container_name: ...
    volumes:
      - "./data:/my_service/data"

    command: >
      ....
```

After running `docker-compose pull`, I run manually `git clone git@github.com:.....`, on the host machine, to clone a private GitHub repo inside the shared directory (mapped as volume). This is working fine but I'd like to know if it's possible to handle this manual step with Docker.

Doing some research I found some examples using a `Dockerfile` but I'd prefer to use only the  `docker-compose.yml` if possible.

Comment: #1 Does your container needs a git repository to work? #2 Why do you need to clone with docker-compose if this is possible inside of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to accomplish this is to write a custom docker file to and address it by docker compose.

Here is an example:

**docker-compose file fragment***

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  my_service:
    build:
      context: 
      dockerfile: my_service.dockerfile

    # ... continue ...
```

**my_service.dockerfile**

```
FROM some_image:some_tag

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y git

RUN cd some_folder && \
    git clone some_uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exemple that use a custom [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) on an nginx image to git clone some repository before starting the server :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - "./data:/my_service/data"
    command: ["bash", "-c", "apt-get update; apt-get install -y git; rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html; git clone https://github.com/cloudacademy/static-website-example /usr/share/nginx/html; nginx -g \"daemon off;\";"]
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

It uses a single line string with all the appropriate commands, that you need to adapt to your use-case. Also, note that depending on the image you use you may or may not be able to add packages.

This may help for a quick workaround, but see @Antonio Petricca answer for a more robust solution.